Deriving braided fusion category from assumptions of a commuting Hamiltonian
An important open mathematical problem in the theoretical foundation of topological order is to prove that the universal properties (braiding and fusion) of point-like excitations in any gapped phase of matter in two dimensional locally interacting lattice systems is described by a unitary modular tensor category (UMTC). This is a very difficult problem (even rigorously formulating this problem takes immense effort) if one does not make any further assumptions. Some progress in this direction are: Kitaev (2003) derived the axioms of UMTC starting from some reasonable physical assumptions (e.g. point-like excitations are classified by superselection sectors and can be moved from one point to another by applying local unitary operators along an arbitrary path connecting the two points). Shi-Kato-Kim (2019) derived fusion rules from assumption of an entanglement area law. This is a remarkable progress, however, (1) there may still be a long way to go from fusion rules to a UMTC (2) it's extremely hard to prove the area law conjecture in 2D.
I wonder if it is possible to have a fully rigorous derivation of a UMTC if we make the stronger assumption of a commuting Hamiltonian, that is, the Hamiltonian of the system  $\hat{H}=\sum_i\hat{h}_i$ is a sum of mutually commuting terms, such as in Kitaev's toric code model and Levin-Wen string-net models. Under this assumption, is it possible to prove that
(1). In 2D, universal properties of point-like excitations are described by a UMTC, of the form $Z(\mathcal{C})$, the Drinfeld center of a unitary fusion category $\mathcal{C}$;
(2). In 3D, universal properties of point-like excitations are described by a  symmetric fusion category.
This should be much easier to prove than the general case, as the  assumption of a commuting Hamiltonian circumvents a lot of technical difficulties; yet it is still highly non-trivial--it's hard to imagine how such a sophisticated mathematical structure like Drinfeld center emerge out of a very simple assumption.
